# Proof that the set of discontinuous points of a Riemann integrable function has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

This comes from proving Lebesgue's Theorem for Riemann integrability as specified in Abbott's *Understanding Analysis*, Theorem 7.6.5. The theorem is as follows:

> Let $f$ be a bounded function defined on the interval $[a, b]$. Then, $f$ is Riemann-integrable if and only if the set of points where $f$ is not continuous has measure zero.

I've followed along with the exercises and have been able to prove the <= direction. I've been stuck on one core point in the proof of the => direction.

The specific area I am struggling with is as follows. The proof starts:

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary, and fix $\alpha > 0$. Because $f$ is Riemann-integrable, there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ of $[a, b]$ such that $U(f, P_\epsilon) - L(f, P_\epsilon) < \alpha \epsilon$.

**Prove that $D^\alpha$ has measure zero.** Where $D^\alpha = \{ x \in [a, b] : f \textrm{ is not }\alpha\textrm{-continuous at }x\}$.

Edit: Including definition of $\alpha$-continuous:

> Let $f$ be defined on $[a, b]$, and let $\alpha > 0$. The function $f$ is *$\alpha$-continuous at* $x\in[a, b]$ if there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $y, z \in (x - \delta, x + \delta)$ it follows that $| f(y) - f(z) | < \alpha$.

If $f$ is *uniformly $\alpha$-continuous* on $[a, b]$, there is a single $\delta > 0$ such that $| x- y | < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(y)| < \alpha$. It follows that if $f$ is $\alpha$ continuous at every point on a compact set $K$, then $f$ is uniformly $\alpha$ continuous on $K$.

---

My attempt so far has taken me down the path of writing:

$$U(f, P_\epsilon) - L(f, P_\epsilon) < \alpha \epsilon$$
$$\sum_k (M_k - m_k)\Delta x_k < \alpha \epsilon$$

Where $M_k$ and $m_k$ are the supremum and infimum, respectively, of $f$ on the interval $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$. Then I attempt to split the intervals into those that contain points in $D^\alpha$ and those that do not. Since the intervals are compact, those intervals containing no points in $D^\alpha$ are uniformly $\alpha$ continuous, which bounds $M_k - m_k < \alpha$ on those intervals (this only holds within some $\delta$, but we can refine the intervals to have smaller length than $\delta$ and I believe this point works out fine).

From here I'm at a bit of a loss, I can't figure out how to take this argument further. I feel that I'm likely missing something relative obvious, so I'd appreciate any nudging in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe defining what you mean by $\alpha$-continuous would be a first step.

Comment: Edit added with definition of $\alpha$-continuous

Comment: What about the sum over only the intervals which contain the points in $D^{\alpha}$? Can we do anything with the fact that $f$ is not $\alpha$-continuous over these intervals?

Comment: Does a set with measure greater than 0 contain an open set? Then f would be discontinuous on an open set and that should be non-integrable. Take this with a big grain of salt, but it might be a start.

Comment: @Predrag3141 Actually it's not necessarily true that a set with positive measure contains an open set, there are certain pathological examples like the Smith-Volterra-Cantor sets. Also I think this would only help for the other direction: currently we're concerned with proving that if a function is integrable, then the set of discontinuities must have measure zero, not the other way around

Comment: @StephenDonovan This would be a proof by contradiction where we assume the set of discontinuities has non-zero measure and the function is non-integrable. But my hope is dashed nonetheless if there is not necessarily an open subset of the discontinuties.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Summing only over the intervals which contain points in $D^\alpha$, I believe all we can use in that region is that $f$ is bounded. So if $[x_{k-1}, x_k] \cap D^\alpha \not = \emptyset$, then we have $M_k - m_k \leq 2 M$ where $| f | \leq M$ as $f$ is bounded.

Comment: I think here the bound from below ends up being more pertinent: if $f$ is not $\alpha$-continuous at these point then it on each interval we must have that $M_k - m_k \geq \alpha,$ right? Meaning $\alpha \epsilon > \sum (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k \geq \alpha \sum \Delta x_k$?

Comment: @Predrag3141 My apologies, that concept does make sense, I guess I just confused myself slightly. But yes, unfortunately it doesn't seem sound

Comment: @StephenDonovan I think that's likely the key insight. With what you shared, you'd get $\sum \Delta x_k  < \epsilon$. Then since the number of intervals is finite, you could construct open intervals around each of those closed intervals, say $O_k$ such that $\sum | O_k | < \epsilon$ and we'd be done.

Answer (score 2):

**Commentary.**

This needs a bit more.  The only "answer" at the moment needs some bit of editing. More importantly there is more to learn here other than the details of a simple proof.

1. For any function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ and any $\alpha>0$ we can (as described here) characterize points of continuity and discontinuity this way:
   $C^\alpha$ is the set of points $x\in [a,b]$ with the property that
   there exists $δ>0$ such that for all $y,z∈(x−δ,x+δ)\cap [a,b]$ it follows that $|f(y)−f(z)|<α$.

Observe:  Each set $C^\alpha$ is open relative to $[a,b]$.  If $C$ is the set of points at which $f$ is continuous then
$$C = \bigcap_{\alpha>0} C^\alpha = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty C^{\frac1n} \tag{1}.$$
This shows that the set of continuity points of an arbitrary function is the intersection of a sequence of open sets.  We call such sets $\cal G_\delta$ sets.

Each set $D^\alpha=[a,b]\setminus C^\alpha$ is closed relative to $[a,b]$.  If $D$ is the set of points at which $f$ is *not* continuous then
$$D= \bigcup_{\alpha>0} D^\alpha = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty D^{\frac1n} \tag{2}.$$
This shows that the set of discontinuity points of an arbitrary function is the union of a sequence of closed sets.  We call such sets $\cal F_\sigma$ sets.
The open sets are called $\cal G$ sets and the closed sets called $\cal F$ (from German and French words respectively).  So these classes of continuity/discontinuity points are pretty simple.  They stand at the very beginning of a huge hierarchy of sets called "Borel sets."

2. The theorem alluded to in the problem is this:

> **Theorem 1**. [19th century version]  A bounded function
> $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of
> points $D$ at which $f$ is discontinuous is the union of a sequence of
> closed sets, each of content [measure] zero.
>
> **Theorem 2**. [20th century version]  A bounded function
> $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is Riemann integrable if and only if the set of
> points $D$ at which $f$ is discontinuous is   measure zero.

It is most curious that many students know only Theorem 2 and give credit to Lebesgue for it.  But Theorem 1 was well-known long before Lebesgue and his teacher Borel reworked measure theory, replacing the older theory of content.   Theorem 2 follows immediately and without more than ten seconds of thought from Theorem 1.  Besides Lebesgue was not the only one to point out this completely trivial fact; W.H. Young and Vitali (among others?) mentioned it.  One needs only to remember  that, for bounded closed sets, content and measure are exactly the same.

3. *Proof of the theorems:*  Following the same reasoning and notation as in the comments and the other answer apply Riemann's criterion for a Riemann integrable function.  If $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\epsilon>0$ and $\alpha>0$,  there is a partition $a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_n=b$ so that  $$\sum_k (M_k-m_k)(x_k-x_{k-1}) < \alpha \epsilon . \tag{3}$$
   Let $A$ be the collection of indexes $k$ for which $(x_{k-1},x_k)$ contains a point of $D^\alpha$.  Clearly $(M_k-m_k) \geq \alpha$ if $k\in A$.  The union
   $$\bigcup_{k\in A} (x_{k-1},x_k)$$
   is an open set with finitely many components that contains all of $D^\alpha$ excepting at most a finite number of points.  The content of that open set is less than $\epsilon$ because
   $$ \alpha \sum_{k\in A} (x_k-x_{k-1}) \leq  \sum_{k\in A} (M_k-m_k)(x_k-x_{k-1}) < \alpha \epsilon.$$

It follows that each set $D^\alpha$ has content [measure] less than $\epsilon$ and so must have content [measure] equal to zero.  The set of discontinuity points of $f$ is then the union of a sequence $\{D^{\frac1n}\}$ of closed sets of content zero.

The other direction is slightly more challenging.  But the OP wanted this one and hence this discussion.  The Riemann criterion goes both ways and is the basis for the proof in both of the directions.

Comment: For those who are interested, I summarized in [this answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/8186/264) a lot details relating to who did what and when regarding Theorems 1 and 2 above. I didn't come upon all these details quickly, or in any single reference. Instead, they slowly accumulated from many sources over a period of 10+ years beginning around 1994 as a side aspect of some other things I was working on. That said, Letta's 1994 paper (see my comments to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/308830/15780)) is probably the single most informative publication on this topic I know of.

Comment: I learned about Hermann Hankel's 1870 attempts and the later proofs by the Italians Volterra and Ascoli from *Dave Renfro*'s posts on this site.  It is quite irritating to see contributions from 19th century mathematicians overlooked by modern textbooks.  In particular, everytime I see "the Lebesgue criterion"  on StackExchange I cringe.  Thanks for the reference to the Letta paper: my Italian is a bit rusty though.

Answer (score -1):

Answer found thanks to Stephen Donovan in the comments.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and fix $\alpha > 0$. As $f$ is Riemann-integrable, there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that:

$$U(f, P_\epsilon) - L(f, P_\epsilon) < \alpha \epsilon$$

This can be written as:

$$\sum_{k}  (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k < \alpha \epsilon$$

Now consider $A = \{ k : (x_{k - 1}, x_k ) \cap D^\alpha \not = \emptyset\}$, the indexes of intervals whose interiors contain points in $D^\alpha$. If we consider summing only over those intervals, we see:

$$\sum_{k\in A} (M_k - m_k)\Delta x_k \leq \sum_{k}  (M_k - m_k) \Delta x_k < \alpha \epsilon$$

As $k \in A$ it follows that $M_k - m_k \geq \alpha$ and therefore:

$$\alpha \sum_{k\in A} \Delta x_k \leq \sum_{k\in A} (M_k - m_k)\Delta x_k  < \alpha \epsilon \implies \sum_{k \in A} \Delta x_k < \epsilon$$

This shows the set $\cup_{k\in A}(x_{k-1},x_k)$ has measure zero.

Recalling that we left off the interval endpoints in our construction of $A$, we consider $B = D^\alpha \cap \{x_0, x_1, ..., x_n\}$, the set of endpoints in $D^\alpha$. This set is finite and therefore has measure zero. The union of measure zero sets is also measure zero and we note:

$$D^\alpha \subseteq  \left(\cup_{k\in A}(x_{k-1},x_k)\right) \cup B$$

Therefore $D^\alpha$ has measure zero.

Comment: Small problem with the details:  if  $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ contains a point of $D^\alpha$ you cannot conclude that $M_k-m_k \geq \alpha$ since it may simply be that the endpoint $x_k$ is the only point in $[x_{k-1},x_k] \cap D^\alpha$.  So you need a slightly more delicate argument to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Is the following modification sufficient? Maintain the above argument to prove that the union of intervals indexed by $A = \{k: (x_{k-1}, x_k) \cap D^\alpha \not = \emptyset\}$ has measure zero, leaving out the endpoints. The set of endpoints, $\{x_0, x_1, ..., x_n\}$ is finite and has measure zero, then we note $D^\alpha \subseteq (\cup_{k\in A} (x_{k-1}, x_k)) \cup \{x_0, x_1, ..., x_n\}$ therefore has measure zero.

Comment: Yes, but i'm sure that you meant to say that the union of those intervals has measure less than $\epsilon$, etc.

Comment: I'm following Abbott's provided definition of measure zero that states a set, $A$, has measure zero if for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a countable collection of open intervals containing $A$ and the sum of lengths of those intervals is less than or equal to $\epsilon$. Being a countable collection of open intervals with total length less than $\epsilon$, would it not follow form the given definition that the union is measure zero?

Comment: It is $D^\alpha$ that has measure zero.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding your point. The union of open intervals is a set in its own right; one which we show has total length less than an arbitrary $\epsilon$. That shows this intermediary set is measure zero in its own right. Just as the finite set of endpoints is another set of measure zero. Of course, the ultimate conclusion is that $D^\alpha$ has measure zero, but is there issue with talking of these intermediary sets having measure zero?

Comment: We agree, just not communicating well.  Your (correct) argument is that, for every $\epsilon$, $D^\alpha$ is contained in the union of a finite set and an open set that has measure smaller than $\epsilon$.  Hence $|D^\alpha|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$ and it must have measure zero.  Agreed?

Comment: Now please delete this statement in your (current) answer since I am sure it is not what you intended: "*This shows the set $\bigcup_{k∈A}(x_{k−1},x_k)$ has measure zero.*"